# How to stop movements of my JFrame on screen/Monitor?

Tags: java, windows, jframe, taskbar

How to stop movements of my `JFrame` on screen/Monitor?
My JFrame size is as much as Screen/Monitor size and my client does not even want to display the task bar.

If I write `myFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`,
it is not allowing to move on screen but showing taskbar, but I don't want to display taskbar.

Comment: And what do you want from us? Write a native code to remove task bar?

Answer (score 1):

You actually want so called "full-screen mode". Take a look on this article to see how to do this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html

Shortly you have to call `device.setFullScreenWindow(myWindow)`

Comment: Thanks for advice Mr. AlexR. As per your input now it is showing fullSize. But Still it is moving on screen when I am moving frema with mouse. My requirement is to stop moving on screen. Please some more inputs required. Thanks